# Given an public key of type CKK_EC, is it possible to find the matching private key using C_FindObjects?

Tags: elliptic-curve, pkcs#11

I have a serialized EC public key - its CKA_EC_PARAMS and CKA_EC_POINT.  There's a matching private key on my token.  Is there any way to find it?

With an RSA key, I can do a FindObjects with CKA_KEY_TYPE=CKK_PRIVATE_KEY and CKA_MODULUS=.  Is there a way to do the same thing with EC keys?  According to the PKCS#11 spec, CKA_EC_POINT isn't an attribute for EC Private Keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a token with support for EC at hand, and it seems that the only way to associate the private and public key will be through the CKA_ID value. No attribute available to test directly the key value.

Actually, even in the case of RSA that's the basic standard method to associate a private and a public key, they ought to be created with identical CKA_ID (that's what the Netscape browser originally did, and everyone copied on that).

They are even some buggy pkcs#11 implementations that won't allow you to read the CKA_MODULUS value of a RSA private key (this is definitevely a bug since the spec explicitly says this value ought to always be public, but it's just one of many bad things frequently happpening with pkcs#11). With them, CKA_ID is the only way even for RSA.